# ($\cos^4x$)($\sin^2x$) in terms of first power of cosine

Tags: trigonometry

I believe that I have his correct but if someone could check it and see that'd be great. Here's a pic!

[image: computation]

Comment: Seems good to me..

Comment: If you're just looking to verify a solution, there's wolfram alpha for that.

Comment: Not a solution, a simplified version of an expression.

Comment: And thanks guys!

Comment: In the 4th line, there’s a denominator of 4 in the first term. It seems to have disappeared in the next line. Also, it looks like $-4\cos^2(2x)$ accidentally became $-\color{red}{2}\cos^2(2x)$ between lines 7 and 8. I didn't look beyond that.

Comment: Yeah your right, I'll have to go over this one again, thanks a lot!